# Replacing strings in file, using patterns from another file

Tags: regex, replace, grep, anonymize

I need to replace many strings in many files using another file with patterns (like a database of strings). It is for anonymizing files.

Example:

File #1:

```
"Administrator";"512";"Built-in account for administering the computer/domain";"False";"False";"Administrator";"True";"True";"True";"S-1-5-21-3445027559-693823181-3401817782-500";"User";"OK";"23. 1. 2012 9:41:34";"20. 1. 2012 16:01:33";"10";"True";*
```

File #2 (the pattern file):

```
Guest;user1

Administrator;user2

system;user3
```

The output in File #1 needs to be

```
"user2";"512";"Built-in account for administering the computer/domain";"False";"False";"user2";"True";"True";"True";"S-1-5-21-3445027559-693823181-3401817782-500";"User";"OK";"23. 1. 2012 9:41:34";"20. 1. 2012 16:01:33";"10";"True";
```

Because the content of File #1 is variable, using some regex did not work in my case. I tried to use `grep` for finding, but it did not work either.

---

So far i tried this one

```
find file1.txt -type f -exec sed -f patt.regular {} \;
```

`patt.regular` is like this:

```
s/10.30.8.204/XX.YY.8.204/g
```

Unfortunately it does not work, I have suspicious, That source file format file1.txt have some issues, becouse nothing gonna happens, but when i delete original file (file1.txt) and create new one, it seems to be ok

Is there a possibility that `sed` could have some format trouble?

Comment: Please add what you tried so far, so we have something to start with. In addition, we may be able to point out what you got wrong in your own attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell,

```
for line in $(cat file2.txt); do sed -i "s/$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 1)/$(echo $line | cut -d ';' -f 2)/g" file1.txt; done
```

does what you want. It needs the files to be called `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and to reside in the current directory.

This does a `sed` for each line in `file2.txt`.

Comment: yes, looks good. thanksnow i have to solve the other - format, problem